# akka typed actors with polymorphic types and type class constraints

Tags: scala, akka, typedactor

Can akka [typed actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/typed-actors.html) work on polymorphic types ?

For example, can I create an actor that carries out the following type safe operation :

```
trait TypedActorInterface{
      def head[T](l:List[T]):T
}
```

?

or create polymorphic Typed Actor:

```
trait TypedActorInterfacePolymorphic[T]{
      def getT:T
}
```

?

or having a type class constraint :

```
trait TypedActorWithTypeClass{
   def show[T:Showable]:String
}
```

?

Are these possible with [Typed Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/typed-actors.html) ?

My guess is that, at least type class constraints are not possible because then that would involve macros/reflection and other magic (because type information would need to be serialized/deserialized automatically).

Maybe the other two are possible, not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in example you don't need to create one more trait for a typed actor. Typed actor is just a proxy. The code outside of the actor knows nothing about actors behind the service.

I don't see any problems with proxying polymorphic traits if a compiler has enough information in place. Please provide your attempts and let's see what went wrong.